# Segoe MDL2 icons in WPF glyphs missing?

Tags: wpf, unicode, fonts, glyph

I downloaded `SegMDL2.ttf` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font, added to the project, set Build Action as Resource and added following to the ResourceDictionary:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="mdl2">/Resources/Fonts/#Segoe MDL2 Assets</FontFamily>
<sys:String x:Key="mdl2 Save">&#xE74E;</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="mdl2 PDF">&#xEA90;</sys:String>
```

Why this displays correct glyph `<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource mdl2}" Text="{StaticResource mdl2 Save}"/>`
,but this does not `<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource mdl2}" Text="{StaticResource mdl2 PDF}"/>`?

[Missing icon in Segoe MDL2 Assets font family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896902/missing-icon-in-segoe-mdl2-assets-font-family)
I don't think this solution is applicable as I want to use embedded resource, not system font (targeting W10 & W7 systems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied font from W10 1909 c:\Windows\Fonts\segmdl2.ttf and all glyphs are now visible. Don't use file hosted on MS website mentioned in question.